# Dynamically adding asp:button to web form using jQuery append() method

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to add an ASP.Net Button programatically using jQuery append method to HTML.
Here is the code:

```
$("#form1 #container").append('<div id="cool"><asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" >/div> ');
```

But somehow it shows this error

> Control 'Button1' of type 'Button' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.

Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to add an `asp:button` to a page via javascript as it is a server-side control.

You can add a plain HTML `<button />` to the page, but it will not be hooked up to postback and viewstate as an `asp:button` would be - you would need some method of doing that manually if required.

Comment: Thanks. I am working on  using a table from sql to create a gallery and add dynamic asp:buttons to it so that when the user clicks the button, it redirects with a session. But as you said it's not possible with jquery so please suggest another way. Thanks

Comment: You're probably best off starting another question about that.

Comment: Try sending a ajax response to the page you are trying to get the asp button on, and then add the element using jquery or js.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible, jquery can only append html controls not server controls. Have a look at this.

[Diff. b/w server and html controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877227/asp-net-difference-between-runat-server-and-server-controls)